# Android studio: Socket.io server and client

Tags: android, server, socket.io, client, netty

I'm trying to run a simple client-server socket.io in android studio, I am basically using socket.io for the client and on the server thread I'm using https://github.com/mrniko/netty-socketio. But the client cannot connect (but i succeeded to connect to another server not implemented on android by someone else). Here is my code for the client and the server:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test_class_activity);
    findViewById(R.id.connect_socket).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Thread clientThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (mSocket==null || !mSocket.connected()) {
                        try {
                            mSocket = IO.socket("http://127.0.0.1:" + PORT);
                        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                            System.out.print(e.getMessage());
                        }

                        if(mSocket!=null) {
                            mSocket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, new Emitter.Listener() {

                                @Override
                                public void call(Object... args) {
                                    Log.d("ActivityName: ", "socket connected");
                                    //socket.disconnect();
                                }
                            }).on(Socket.EVENT_MESSAGE, new Emitter.Listener() {

                                @Override
                                public void call(final Object... args) {
                                    Log.d("ActivityName: ", "msg received: " + args[0].toString());
                                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void run() {
                                            ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.response_server)).setText(args[0].toString());
                                        }
                                    });
                                    mSocket.emit(Socket.EVENT_MESSAGE, "salut Sam c est Adrien. J ai recu ton message: \"" + args[0].toString() + "\"");
                                }
                            });
                            mSocket.connect();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            clientThread.start();
        }
    });

    findViewById(R.id.start_server).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                server();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

private static void server() throws InterruptedException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    if(server!=null) {
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.setHostname("localhost");
        config.setPort(PORT);
        server = new SocketIOServer(config);
        server.addEventListener("toServer", String.class, new DataListener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onData(SocketIOClient client, String data, AckRequest ackRequest) {
                client.sendEvent("toClient", "server recieved " + data);
            }
        });
        server.addEventListener("message", String.class, new DataListener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onData(SocketIOClient client, String data, AckRequest ackRequest) {
                client.sendEvent("toClient", "message from server " + data);
            }
        });
        server.start();
    }
}

}
```

Do you have an idea why my client cannot connect?

Answer (score 0):

Try using 0.0.0.0 instead of 127.0.0.1, it accepts requests on all interfaces

```
mSocket = IO.socket("http://0.0.0.0:" + PORT);
```